# How do I include an Ivy Dependency in subversion repo

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, ivy, ivyde

So, since I've been unable to find a way to resolve our dependency issues by including everything from external sources I've turned to Eclipse / IvyDE for ant / Ivy integration.

With that said, I normally include a lib like this:

```
<dependency org="org.jsoup" name="jsoup" rev="1.6.3"/>
```

However what if I want to look at something in our own intranet?

Example, if the folder holding the jar is somewhere like this:

```
https://prdsvn01.company.intra.net/repo/libName/
```

and I want to include lib.jar into my folder.

I've been relatively unable to find ivysettings.xml in this implementation of eclipse, nor am I confident that I'd be able to get it right if I could.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following ivy settings file:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>

    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>

        <url name="my-repo">
            <artifact pattern="http://myserver/myrepo/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
        </url>
    </resolvers>

    <modules>
        <module organisation="org.mycompany" resolver="my-repo"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Is configured to retrieve artifacts from Maven Central by default, and local artifacts from a HTTP server.

## Update

### ivy.xml

Nothing special in the ivy file. Just declare the dependencies and which configuration to associate them with:

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
</configurations>

<dependencies>
    <!-- compile dependencies -->
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.4" conf="compile->default"/>
    <dependency org="org.mycompany" name="my-module" rev="1.0" conf="compile->default"/>

</dependencies>
```

Note:

- It's ivy best practice to use configurations.

### build.xml

```
<target name="resolve" dependencies="Resolve build dependencies">
    <ivy:resolve/>

    <ivy:report todir='build/reports' graph='false' xml='false'/>

    <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
    ..  
</target>
```

Notes:

- The ivycachepath task transforms an ivy configuration into a populated ANT classpath. Very useful.
- The ivy report task tells you the jars on the classpath(s)

### Ivy resolve build output

All the magic is in the settings file. Running the build produces the following:

```
[ivy:resolve]   found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.4 in central
[ivy:resolve]   found org.mycompany#my-module;1.0 in my-repo
..
[ivy:resolve] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar ...
..
[ivy:resolve] downloading http://myserver/myrepo/org.mycompany/my-module/1.0/my-module.jar ...
```

Notes:

- The **my-repo** resolver is used for modules with a "org.mycompany" groupId.
- Everything else comes from the default resolver, Maven Central.

Comment: Can you add in a quick local dependency in ivy.xml to show me the difference in how I would differentiate the two?